# How to make python compatible on all computers?

Tags: python, dependencies, compatibility

I wrote an interesting script that I want to share with people, but it won't run on other computers unless they have the same dependencies installed. How do I bundle the dependencies into the script package so that other people don't need to install dependencies to run the script? Like, maybe let the script reference the dependencies in the same folder that the script is packaged in.

I want to keep it open source and share my code, so I don't want to use cx_freeze to turn it into an exe.

Comment: How about using pip?  It can handle installing dependencies.

Comment: I thought pip was only used for installing packages, but know that you mention it, I realize that it must also create packages. I'll take a look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you create a virtual environment.

```
 Step 1:
     >> pip install virtualenv

 Step 2:
     >> cd my_project_folder
     >> virtualenv env
     Note: In this case I named my environment "env" you 
     can call it whatever you want.

 Step 3: Activate your virtual environment
     >> source env/bin/activate

 Step 4: Install whatever libraries your program needs.
       ex. >> pip install Flask

 Step 5: Create a requirements doc.
      >> pip freeze > requirements.txt
      Note: Be sure to update your requirements.txt doc 
      whenever you install new packages.
```

When you post your project on open source forums people can then pip install your requirements.txt file to have the same environment you had when you made it.

Answer (score 0):

Try packaging/bundling up your application using [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/); This us used for example by [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to ship a cross-platform compatible binary (*where `docker-compose` is written in Python*).

In it's simplest usage it's as simple as:

```
pip install pyinstaller  # Get pyinstaller
pyinstaller -F /path/to/myscript.py
```

You'll end end up with a bundled executable that you can share that includes all dependencies.

**Note:** You'll probably have to repeat these steps for other platforms / operating systems you want to support (e.g: Windows); but I have no practical experience in doing so so refere to the [pyinstaller Documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/) for how to bundle for other platforms.

**Update:** To provide both pre-built/bundled distributions of your program as well as downloadable source code simply follow the above advice for the first part and follow the [Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) for declaring dependencies in your `setup.py` making it easy for other to either `pip install` or `git clone` and `python setup.py install`.

Comment: The thing is that I want my code to be open source and run in python, so I don't want to make it an exe file. But, if I can't figure that out, I'll be sure to go with your suggestion, Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing special about an ``.exe`` per se; your application can still OSS -- You are just distributing pre-built/packaged binaries. an EXE is not much different to an ELF (*We just don't have normally ``.elf`` extensions on executable in Linux!*)

Comment: I understand, but let's say I want to put the script up on Github so that people can download and run it without having to download other dependencies. I can't upload an exe/elf/bin.

Comment: Why not? Docker do exactly this for docker-compose up over at: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases (*LInux and OS X binaries*).

Comment: I see that they have the executables for their program on the page, but they also allow people to download and run the program from the source code on this page: https://github.com/docker/compose. I am not opposed to the exectuable form, I just want to know how to do both forms (executable and source) like they do.